# No error, but mongo doesn't update either

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update a bunch of records from my database. Here is the command I used :

```
> db.getCollection('slices').update({}, {$set: {rms: 'TODO'}})
```

But there is a bunch of records that are not updated :

```
> db.getCollection('slices').find({rms: {$type: 1}}).count()
30301
```

I have no clue how this could even happen ... Any idea?

Comment: Updates by default are singular you need to add a third param of `{multiple:true}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The update query takes an options object:

```
db.collection.update(
   <query>,
   <update>,
   { upsert: <boolean>, multi: <boolean> }
)
```

So to update multiple documents set the multi flag to true:

```
db.getCollection('slices').update({}, {$set: {rms: 'TODO'}}, {multi: true})
```